# Некорректная работа Physics2D.OverlapCapsuleAll

Tags: c#, unity3d

Всем доброго времени суток!
Делаю на unity игру, решил использовать функцию `Physics2D.OverlapCapsuleAll`, так как она лучше всего подходит для моих целей. Внезапно я столкнулся с непонятным багом, который выражается в странной работе данной функции. Путем простых вычислений методом тыка, я понял, что область капсулы, которую воспроизводит данная функция, повернута на 90 градусов. То есть, капсула должна лежать горизонтально, но по факту она стоит. Вот мой код в fixedUpdate:

```
        Vector2 overlapPoint = new Vector2(transform.position.x, (transform.position.y - 0.5f));
        colliders = Physics2D.OverlapCapsuleAll(overlapPoint, new Vector2(1f, 0.125f), CapsuleDirection2D.Horizontal, 0f);
```

Comment: CapsuleDirection2D.Vertical ?!

Comment: Для чего вы удалили свой предыдущий вопрос и задали точно такой же?

Comment: Да, в этом то и дело, что я ставлю мод "Horizontal", а капсула по факту Вертикальная.
Пересоздал вопрос что бы изменить формулировку вопроса.

Comment: Вопрос надо не пересоздавать, а править.

Comment: Да, в пустом проекте тот же баг, поле капсулы оказывается повернуто на 90 градусов. НО, с тем же overlapBoxAll такого бага нет.

Answer (score 0):

Похоже на то, что ты создаешь капсулу шириной 1 и высотой 0.125, а потом поворачиваешь ее на 90 с CapsuleDirection2D.Horizontal. Может тебе поменять местами координаты в конструкторе new Vector2(0.125f, 1). Сам не пробовал..

Comment: Не уверен, на сколько это правдиво. Ведь если взять просто CapsuleCollider2D и повесить на GameObject, то с модом Horizontal и size: (1, 0.125) все работает корректно, а если передавать эти параметры функции Physics2D.OverlapCapsuleAll, то происходит как раз этот баг.

Comment: Может у тебя этот объект дочерний к какому-то еще в иерархии.. может он внутри какого-то пустого трансформа с повёрнутыми осями. Хотя, ты б уже заметил наверное. Вообще, вот здесь обсуждается OverlapCapsule https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-use-the-new-physics2d-overlapcapsule-capsulecast.455232/ . Может это прояснит что-то.